# How to integrate Pentaho reporting in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting, pentaho

I want to implement reporting in asp.net mvc and i have selected Pentaho for the same. How do i go about implementing this in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentho runs using the Tomcat app server, which runs in a Java environment.

Your best bet will be to create a frame and call a web service that will return the report, (or you can use AJAX).

Normally, Pentaho will require a login so you will have to fiddle with the authentication settings on the Pentaho server, or embed the username and password on the xaction.

The trick is using the **ServiceAction** servlet, so searching on that keyword will provide some answers, as in this example (for PHP).

http://bdietzblog.blogspot.com/2008/12/pentaho-bi-server-using-action.html